# Add image from file to Telerik Radgrid column

Tags: vb.net, winforms, telerik-grid

I have a Winforms app with a Telerik RadGridView.  Our HR dept has employee pictures in a known location on our file server.  I am trying to include the employee picture on my RadGrid using the picture file.

I created a column of type ImageColumn as shown:

```
Dim imageColumn As New GridViewImageColumn
imageColumn.Name = "ImageColumn"
imageColumn.HeaderText = "Picture"
imageColumn.ImageLayout = ImageLayout.Zoom
RadGridView1.MasterTemplate.Columns.Add(imageColumn)
```

Then I tried to loop through each row of the radGrid and assign a picture to the imageColumn:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To RadGridView1.Rows.Count - 1
    RadGridView1.Rows(i).Cells("ImageColumn").Value = "c:\myPicture.jpg"
Next
```

**Note**: In this example I'm simply trying to assign the same picture to every row.  Later I will add logic to add the specific picture required.

Running this code produces a blank image column. No error is returned.

I have tried image values of `c:\myPicture.jpg`, `c:\\\myPicture.jpg`, and `@c:\myPicture.jpg`

What am I doing wrong?